# Использование слова "каков", "каковы"

Tags: стилистика

Скажите пожалуйста, является ли нарушением правил/норм русского языка выражение 
"каковы ваши образование и профессия"?

Если да, то можете пожалуйста привести правило?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это не нарушение. Звучит немного как иностранщина, это да. Но тем не менее никаких правил не нарушает. Видимо, дело в том, что язык стремиться к экономии средств, а вопрос тот же можно задать и без слова "каковы". Это стилистика, на неё четких правил подчас и не найти, так что придется поверить на слово.

Другой вопрос, почему многие так не любят это слово, даже в тех случаях когда оно вполне уместно вообще по всем критериям... У меня нет разумных объяснений. Надо спрашивать у тех, кто против этого слова.

Answer (score 2):

Каковы ваши образование и профессия? **Мне кажется, что это некорректный вопрос.**

Можно спросить: **какое у вас образование и профессия**.  Ответ, к примеру, будет такой: у меня **высшее** образование, по профессии я врач.

**Пояснение**

Вопросу "какой" обычно соответствует **постоянный** признак, в то время как вопросу "каков" соответствует **оценочный**  признак, отнесенный к **текущему** моменту.

**Возможен такой диалог:** Какая у вас профессия? - Я геолог. - Ну и какова ваша профессия? - Он интересная, увлекательная, но не всем подходит.

**Примеры для вопроса "каков"**

― А из себя **каков**? На вид каков? Небось, плут продувной? [И. С. Тургенев. Конец Чертопханова (1872)]

**Каков** он тебе показался? Печален, задумчив? [А. С. Пушкин. Барышня-крестьянка (1830)].

Причем не так уж важно, **каков** интеллектуальный уровень обсуждаемого произведения.

**Каков** объем сегодняшних запасов газа на Ямале, в том числе в арктической зоне округа?